# Words for tongue in Tungusic

Tags: proto-indo-european, comparative-linguistics, reconstruction, altaic-hypothesis, tungusic

In Tungusic there are attested the following words for tongue:

- Manchu: *ilenggu*
- Nanai: *siŋmu*
- Evenki: *inni*, *čoli*

Wikitionary postulates that the words *ilenggu*, *siŋmu* and *inni* are related and gives reconstruction *[xilŋü](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Tungusic/xil%C5%8B%C3%BC)* for Proto-Tungusic. I do not know who is the author who proposed this reconstruction though.

On the other hand, the Evenki synonym *čoli* is similar to other Altaic and Uralic reconstructions:

- Mongolian *hel*
- Chuvash *čelxe*
- Sakha *tol*
- Turkish *dil*
- Nivkh *hilx*
- Finno-Ugric *keeli*
- Proto-Uralic reconstruction *käle*

My conjecture: The Proto-Tungusic reconstruction for the first root is wrong and instead it should be connected to PIE **dn̥ǵʰwéh₂s*.

On what this reconstruction, **xilŋü* is based? It looks to me that the autor is artificially trying to fit the reconstruction to look similar to the other root, which is synonymous.

I reconstruct the original root which is cognate to *čoli* as **tkel-* and the root which is cognate to *inni* as something like **dyungu*

Thus, my question: on what the Wikitionary reconstruction of the word for tongue in Tungusic is based?

Answer (score 2):

Your question contains a wrong assumption. You take for granted that Evenki *čoolii* 'tongue' is considered a descendant of PTg **xilŋü* 'tongue' together with its synonym *inńi*, but this is not the case. These words come from two different roots. Evenki *čoolii* is probably a deverbal noun from a root meaning 'to gossip, chat, babble', and has a parallel in Negidal *čoolïï-* 'id.' (SSTM 2: 405), while Evenki *inńi* < PTg **xilŋü*.

If you take a closer look at the page dedicated to [**xilŋü*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Tungusic/xil%C5%8B%C3%BC) on Wiktionary, you will realize that it does not list *čōlī* under this root. The only forms cited are Evenki *inńi*, Oroqen (*sic*) *iŋi*, Nanai *siŋmu*, Orok *sinu* and Manchu *ilenggu*. I suspect *iŋi* is really an Oroch word mislabelled as Oroqen. To these, we might also add Even *jenŋä*, Solon *iŋi*, Negidal *ińŋi*, Udihe *iŋi*, Ulch *sińu* and Jurchen 亦冷吉 **(h)ilenggi*, or **(h)ilenggu* (see Kane 1989: 315, #885). In Nanai, the doublet *sirmu* is attested in the Kur-Urmi subdialect (SSTM 1: 136-37). The reconstruction **xilŋü* was developped by Sergej Starostin, Anna Dybo and Oleg Mudrak (2003), the same authors of the highly controversial Altaic Etymological Dictionary. Their reconstruction of Proto-Tungusic is heavily based on Cincius' (1949) previous ideas and on her two-volume etymological dictionary of Manchu-Tungus (1975-77), but here and there they take into consideration some of Benzing's (1955) alternative proposals.

Setting aside the complicated history of the Tungusic vocalism, I would say the proto-form **xilŋü* is acceptable, because it is based on a couple of well-established facts about Proto-Tungusic phonology, such as the existence of the spirant **x* phoneme and the reflexes of the cluster **lŋ*. Initial **x* is systematically lost in the Northern (Evenki, Even, Negidal, etc.) and Transitional (Udihe and Oroch) branches, while is preserved in Southern Tungusic (Nanai, Orok, etc.), though only partially in Jurchen and Manchu. Its reflexes are *x-*, or *s-* before a front vowel (like in this case) in Nanai, Orok and Ulch, as you can see in the second paragraph. The consonant cluster **lŋ* evolves as *ńŋ*, *nŋ*, or simply *ŋ*, in most languages through partial assimilation of the lateral element to the following nasal. However, Tugur-Chumikan and Ayan dialects of Evenki, which have *ilŋi* beside Standard Evenki *inńi* and Barguzin Evenki *ińŋi*, show a more direct evidence of the original **l* of the cluster. The same can be said for Kur-Urmi Nanai *sirmu*, which substitutes a rhotic for the lateral.

Turkic **til* ~ **tïl* 'tongue', Mongolic **kelen* 'id.' and Uralic **käle* 'id.' have nothing to do with Tungusic **xilŋü*, despite the superficial phonetic similarity. By the way, the Chuvash form is *čĕlxe*, not ***čelxe*, and the Yakut one is *tïl*, not ***tol* (see Räsänen 1969: 478). Same for Amur, North Sakhalin and East Sakhalin Nivkh *hilx* 'tongue'. You would need a fair amount of comparative gymnastics in order to argue for their cognacy, and the required phonetic changes would be in any case unsystematic (by which I mean they would most likely be valid only for the word for 'tongue').

When reasoning about similarities and common patterns across languages, you should resist the tentation of thinking that two or more languages are related to each other just because they (or their ancestors) have one or two words that sound similar. Keep in mind Occam's razor: you should sift through alternative explanations that are much simpler before postulating the existence of a macro-family of languages. As for the word for 'tongue', the fact that it often contains the sounds /l/ or /d/ and /k/, /g/, /x/ or /ŋ/ in many languages may be due to phonosymbolism. Such sounds exemplify the full range of mobility of the tongue, i.e. /l/ and /d/, being alveolar, are the most advanced sounds the tongue can produce, while /k/, /g/, /x/ and /ŋ/, being velar, are the most retracted. In this sense, it is almost like the forms /lVk/, /dVŋgV/, /kVlV/, etc. display a deictic gesture, and therefore, by virtue of such extra-linguistic property, they end up being quite common in natural languages, but they do not constitute evidence for a genetic relationship.

---

### References

- Benzing, Johannes. 1955. *Die tungusischen Sprachen: Versuch einer vergleichenden Grammatik*. Wiesbaden: Verlag der Akademie der Wissenschaften und Literatur in Mainz.
- Cincius, Vera I. 1949. *Sravnitel’naja Fonetika Tunguso-Man’čžurskix Jazykov*. Leningrad: Izdatel’stvo «Nauka».
- Kane, Daniel. 1989. *The Sino-Jurchen Vocabulary of the Bureau of Interpreters*. Bloomington: Indiana University.
- Räsänen, Martti. 1969. *Versuch eines etymologischen Wörterbuchs der Türksprachen*. Helsinki: Suomalais-Ugrilainen Seura.
- SSTM = Cincius, Vera I. (ed.). 1975-1977. *Sravnitel’nyj slovar’ tunguso-man’čžuskix jazykov, Materialy k ètimologičeskomu slovarju*. Vols. 1-2. Leningrad: Izdatel’stvo «Nauka».
- Starostin, Sergej A., Dybo, Anna V. and Mudrak, Oleg A. 2003. *Etymological Dictionary of the Altaic Languages*. Leiden: Brill.

Comment: "You take for granted that Evenki čoolii 'tongue' is considered a descendant of PTg *xilŋü 'tongue'" - no, I did not consider this. Possibly, you misunderstood. My point is, these are two different ancient roots.

Comment: "You would need a fair amount of comparative gymnastics in order to argue for their cognacy" - no, no, I did not argue they are related, my point is AGAINST it. You've misunderstood.

Comment: Do you think Nivkh hilx is cognate to Tungusic *xilŋü?

Comment: @Anixx, my view is that all these terms, including Nivkh *hilx*, are unrelated. In my opinion, their similarity is due to sound symbolism.

Comment: @Anixx, you write: "It looks to me that the autor is artificially trying to fit the reconstruction to look similar to the other root, which is synonymous". I thought you meant to say that the editors of Wiktionary (not necessarily you specifically) considered **xilŋü* and *čoolii* related, otherwise why do you point out the artificial attempt to make their reconstruction similar?